# CSS - why top element always remains on top while rotating 180deg?

Tags: html, css

I have a container with two elements absolutely positioned. While rotating the container on hover, why the top elements always remains on top even when the container is rotated by 180deg. why don't we see the bottom element then?

```css
body {
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.container {
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 250px;
  transition: all 3s;
}

.container:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.item-1 {
  height: 120%;
  background: orange;
  /* z-index: -1; */
}

.item-2 {
  background: cyan;
  /*    z-index: 1; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class=" item item-1"></div>
  <div class=" item item-2">Hover Over Me!</div>
</div>
```

**code:** https://jsfiddle.net/rj5b9dhc/

---

*I have the solution, but I'm curious why above  code doesn't work*

**solution code:** https://jsfiddle.net/512p9x3r/1/

Answer (score 1):

Because of `backface-visibility: hidden;` in item-2 css in solution code.

Check this: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_backface-visibility.asp)

**Updated**:
When `.item` (two items) height is `100%`, `.item-2` have no height in it css and covering `100%` of container and `.item-1` `height` is `120%` (it's mean that it `height` is `20%` more than `.item-2`) and covering `20%` of container.
Cause of that `.item-1` is before `.item-2`, `.item-1` will be showing on `.item-2`.

as the Reference explained:

> This property is useful when an element is rotated. It lets you choose
> if the user should see the back face or not.

When container has rotated, `.item-2` will be hidden.

Comment: thank you and sorry for my mistake in writing, I wasn't asking how the solution works but why the code in my question doesn't work.

Comment: no problem, answer has updated.  So if it is your answer please accept answer to close this

Comment: My question is not about `backface-visibility: hidden;`. I know it and how it works. I have two elements, item-1 at bottom and item-2 at top in stacking and hence we are seeing the top element. I just wanted to know when we **rotate** the parent by `180deg`, **the bottom element(item-1) should be on top** then why are we still seeing the top element(itme-2)

Comment: actually `transform: rotate` is an method to flip (mirroring) an object, for example an image (or a text) have not a back page, so it be rotated  as mirror.[Check it out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotateY())